# JIRA Plugins: What do you use?

Tags: plugins, jira

JIRA is a very extensible bug/task tracking tool. As such, newcomers feel lost as to what plugins they should install.

Please share your thoughts what plugins (both free and paid) that you consider a "must-add" for JIRA!

Comment: This would make a nice example question here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops

Comment: "Jira Work Calendar" for time tracking in "Calendar" and timesheets: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/1211847. The plugin is free and really good, so please forgive me self-advertising :-).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are the plugins I couldn't live without:

Timesheet report - Summarizes any user's time spent over a weekly period: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/Timesheet+report+and+portlet

Charting plugin - Generate charts from any issue navigator: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Charting+Plugin

Subversion plugin - Link and view subversion commit history to a JIRA issue: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Subversion+plugin

Labels plugin - Lets you tag any JIRA issue and search on tags: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Labels+Plugin

Comment: Is this the charting plugin? https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JCHART/JIRA+Charting+Plugin (original link no longer works)

Answer (score 9):

We use JIRA Labels plug-in, which allows to add a "tags" field: http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAEXT/JIRA+Labels+Plugin

Plugins that stand out the most (paid and free) are mentioned on Atlassian's plugin page: 
https://plugins.atlassian.com/search/by/jira

And the company I work for develops JIRA Client, a desktop client for JIRA (paid unless you're open-source): http://almworks.com/jiraclient

Answer (score 7):

We use [Tempo Plugin](http://www.tempoplugin.com/) extensively for time tracking, project management, planning and billing.

We are also big fans of [Greenhopper](http://www.atlassian.com/software/greenhopper/) for project management (Scrum/KanBan).

Answer (score 4):

We use quite a few extra JIRA plugins; the charts for visualizing find/fix ratios etc., Release status plugin for a nice visualization of how each release stands, the SVN integration, Linker and Activity Stream plugins for integration with Confluence, and the Firefox search portlet that lets you use JIRA as a search engine option in Firefox.

Some of our developers also like the Eclipse plugin for JIRA that lets them manage their list of issues direct from the IDE.

The only paid plugin we tried out was Greenhopper, since we are an agile shop, but we didn't find it useful enough to be worth buying.

Answer (score 3):

We really liked the following:

- Create and Link: Allows us to create an issue, then create another issue that automatically gets linked to the original
- JIRA Suite Utilities: Incredibly useful plug-in!  The most helpful feature was it's ability to make field's required after a transition.
- JIRA Misc Workflow Extensions: multiple useful conditions and validators for work flows.

Answer (score 3):

To integrate Jira with Saleforce or SugarCRM you should consider [Go2group CRM plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/5198)

Answer (score 3):

We use [ScreenMail for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.dreambroker.jira.plugins.dreambroker-jira-plugin) as it lets us create screencasts to our issues. It removes the need to write long descriptions of specifications or bugs. Screencasts makes it possible for me to record my screen and talk whats on my mind to my mic. Anyone who has access to the issues can watch the video later.

This has given me more freedom to work whenever as I do not need to call a meeting always when something more complicated has come up. Work with overseas partners has also been easier as I am able to work in my own timezone most of the time.

Whats important here is that you do not need to install any additional software or rent harddrive space. The plugin does everything for you. Just install the plugin and start recording.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [JIRA Workflow Visualization Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JVIZ) very useful when first setting up Jira workflows - it gives a pictorial representation of your workflows, which makes it easier to view than the list of steps that Jira gives you by default.

Answer (score 2):

For customizing the way Jira works and adding new features:

- [Behaviours Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.plugin.Behaviours/version/275)
- [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss/version/7)

With this to you could practically do almost anything. I used it to write Issues 24hrs notifications, sending email from templates that are saved in Confluence, automatic issue moving, closing, cloning and sub-issue creating, and much more...

To complete the last two plugins, some plugins that add special features to make life easier:

- [JIRA Toolkit Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.toolkit/version/114)
- [JIRA Workflow Toolbox](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.fca.jira.plugins.workflowToolbox.workflow-toolbox/version/12)

A nice plugin to display external pages:

- [Jira Custom Content Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.tngtech.jira.plugins.customcontent.jira-gadget-custom-content/version/2)

Answer (score 0):

For more advanced JIRA reports, charts and dashboards there is [eazyBI application with standard JIRA integration](https://eazybi.com/help/jira) as well as [installable eazyBI reports and charts plugin for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.eazybi.jira.plugins.eazybi-jira).